# How to say email "mis-sent" in a business manner?

Tags: business-language

If I want to tell my colleague by email that I've sent an email to some business clients unintentionally and would like to notify my colleague, how should I say the action "mis-sent"?

I thought about "email sent unintentionally", but I think it involves too much personal feelings. Can I have another word which is more business like (or objective)?

Answer (score 6):

Misaddressed, wrongly addressed, misdirected, sent in error. Those first three are if it was to have been sent but not to that recipient (i.e., was wrongly addressed); the last is more general.

These are off the top of my head, not Best Business Practices™.

Comment: +1 for "sent in error" or you could say some clients will have an email "received in error" ;)

Answer (score 2):

`mal-addressed` or `mis-routed`

Comment: +1 for 'misrouted', though I'd spell it without the hyphen (as I just did, in fact).

Answer (score 0):

sometimes use "mistakenly sent"